# Python Multiple key in a text file

Tags: python

My Data is as below:

```
Name: Joe
Age: 26
Property: 1 of 3
Item : Car
Make: Toyota
Model: Corolla
Year:2006
Property: 2 of 3
Item : House
Address : new Street
Cost : 20000
Property: 3 of 3
Item: Stocks
Investment: 1000
Name: Blogg
Age: 28
Property: 1 of 2
Item : Bike
BikeMake: Harley
BikeModel: IronRod
BikeYear:2018
Property: 2 of 2
Item: Stocks
Investment: 2000
```

I need the result to look like below:

| Name | Age | Property | Item | Make | Model | Year | Address | Cost | Investment | BikeMake | BikeMode | BikeYear |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 26 | 1 of 3 | Car | Toyota | Corolla | 2006 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Joe | 26 | 2 of 3 | House |  |  |  | new Street | 20000 |  |  |  |  |
| Joe | 26 | 3 of 3 | Stocks |  |  |  |  |  | 1000 |  |  |  |
| Blogg | 28 | 1 of 2 | Bike |  |  |  |  |  |  | Harley | Ironrod | 2018 |
| Blogg | 26 | 3 of 3 | Stocks |  |  |  |  |  | 2000 |  |  |  |

My code is currently

```
for line in t:
    print(line)
    key, _, value = line.partition(": ")
    if not value:    # separator was not found
        value = "NA"
    if "Name" in key:
        stuff[index] = {"Reference": [value]}  # Always use a list as vale
        current_key = index
        index += 1
    elif key not in stuff[current_key]:  # If key does not exist
        stuff[current_key][key] = [value]  # Create key with value in a list.
    else:
        stuff[current_key][key].append(value)
```

My current results are being pivoted by the **Name** key (e.g)

| Name | Age | Property | Item | Make | Model | Year | Address | Cost | Investment | BikeMake | BikeMode | BikeYear |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 26 | 1 of 3,2 of 3,3 of 3 | Car,House,Stocks | Toyota | Corolla | 2006 | New Street | 20000 | 1000 |  |  |  |
| Blogg | 28 | 1 of 2,2 of 2 | Bike,Stocks |  |  |  |  |  | 2000 | Harley | IronRod | 2018 |

Comment: what is the data structure of the desired outcome?

Comment: what about your data, it seems your are expecting multiple values for some or all items? it this is the case your sample data is not representative for what your data actually might look like. What about the order of lines in your file? is it guaranteed that Name and Age come first and that Property starts a new Item of some kind?

Comment: updated data. Yes expecting multiple values of some items. Name and Age come first always. They do not repeat.

Comment: Why not use YAML or JSON instead?